Postgres function with variable query return
I have a do statement that I would like to turn into a function, but I am unsure of how the return type should work. This is the current do statement:
do $$
declare 
practice text;
date_columns text;
value_columns text;
query_text text;
query_result text;
begin
practice = 'practice1';
select string_agg(distinct '"' || service || '" numeric', ',')
into date_columns
from (select service_date from public.payment_application pa where practicename = practice) as dates(service);

select string_agg(distinct '(''''' || service || ''''')', ',')
into value_columns
from (select service_date from public.payment_application pa where practicename = practice) as dates(service);

query_text := 'SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   ''SELECT post_date, service_date as date, applied_amount as amount
     FROM public.payment_application where practicename=''''practice1''''
     ORDER BY 1, 2'', ''values ' || value_columns || '''
) AS ct (post_date text, ' || date_columns || ');';

execute query_text;
end $$;

I have seen the table return type, but that seems like it needs to have a specific column definition, but my query will vary and may have different columns depending on the parameters passed to the function.
Is there a way that I can return the result of query_text from a function like this?

DO will never return anything, you have to create a function that returns a fixed number of columns, with the correct names and data types.

I would like to turn this into a function, but I need it to be able to return a variable sized result. Is there any way to do that, or do you have to predetermine the number of columns?

No, you have to predetermine the number of columns and their data type

Not sure why you might need this but you may consider returning a JSON  value or a table with a single JSON column

I was just trying to create a function that could create a crosstab starting at a specific date that would work until the current date, no matter when I ran the function. I ended up just creating a python script to handle the varying dates and that worked just fine. Not quite as clean, but worked well all the same. Thanks for the help!
